# Overlay Picture Box texture and structure

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2012, overlay

I have a rectangle shape in which I have a picture box component with a picture:
[image: Idk]

And I want to change the pictures texture without destroying the outline:
[image]

I can't create the image in an editor, because I have many images and many textures, it wouldn't be efficient. I know it can be done in Visual Studio and I don't think it was done with opacity (it would be more brighter or the outlines would be less visible. Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: @Grant Winney It doesn't matter what texture do I want to apply (in this case a wooden), I have the texture stored. I have these images from a program that I know was created in VS. I couldn't find any article about it, that's why I'm asking you.

Comment: So, you basically want code to apply textures to pictures?

Comment: @rene Yeah, I know it sound's crazy, but I saw a program created in VS doing that. I can post a video if you want for better explanation.

Comment: I rather have you add the code that add that image to the picture box. A video will not help much as not many here want to sit through a video to understand were you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a routine that multiplies the structure's brightness over the texture's colors.

Here is one:

```
public static Bitmap Multiply(Bitmap bmp0, Bitmap bmp1)
{
    int Bpp = 4;  // assuming an effective pixelformat of 32bpp

    var bmpData0 = bmp0.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp0.Width, bmp0.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp0.PixelFormat);
    var bmpData1 = bmp1.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp1.PixelFormat);

    int len = bmpData0.Height * bmpData0.Stride;
    byte[] data0 = new byte[len];
    byte[] data1 = new byte[len];
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData0.Scan0, data0, 0, len);
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData1.Scan0, data1, 0, len);

    float brighter =  1.3f;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += Bpp)
    {
        //float h = (data1[i] + data1[i + 1] + data1[i + 2]) / (255 * 3f);
        // assuming a grayscale structure overlay:
        float h = data1[i] / 255f;
        h *= brighter;    
        data0[i]     = (byte)(Math.Min(255, (data0[i] * h)));
        data0[i + 1] = (byte)(Math.Min(255, (data0[i + 1] * h)));
        data0[i + 2] = (byte)(Math.Min(255, (data0[i + 2] * h)));
        if (Bpp == 4) data0[i + 3] = 255;   // shouldn't be necessary
    }
    Marshal.Copy(data0, 0, bmpData0.Scan0, len);
    bmp0.UnlockBits(bmpData0);
    bmp1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);
    return bmp0;
}
```

It makes a few assuptions:

- Both images have the same size
- Both images have the same effective pixel format
- The first image is the texture, the 2nd the structure
- The structure is grayscale. (If it isn't uncomment the setting of `h`)

Notes:

- To my amazement I found that even though the source images are reported to be `24bpp` by IrfanView they are 32bpp when the routine works with them. Looks like GDI+ turns every `PNG` into `32bpp` by default.
- The routine uses only one channel of the structure map. If it is a colored images you may want to change the calculation of `h`. The one using all 3 channels doesn't calculate the perceived brightness, but this should do for the purpose.
- Since the body of the structure isn't white the overall result is a bit darker than the original pattern. I have added a correction factor `brighter` to nudge `h` up a little and code that limits the bytes to 255. Don't make `brighter` too large or the lights of the structure will get lost..

Here is how you can use it:

```
string structure = @"d:\structure_01.png";
string pattern   = @"d:\pat_01.png";

// cleanup old bitmap!
if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();

using ( Bitmap bm1 = new Bitmap(structure) )
{
    Bitmap bm0 = new Bitmap(pattern);
    pictureBox1.Image = Multiply(bm0, bm1);
}
```

Here are the two source images and the result:

[image: texture][image: structure][image: overlay]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I still have some problems. If I understand it right, the bmp0 and bmp1 are the Picture Boxes? If not, how do I tell which images it has to use. And the second one, how do I run this script, for example on load of the form.

Comment: No, bmp0 and bmp1 are Images. You add the method to your form and call it by feeding in the Images you have and make the result the PictureBox's Image.. I have added an example. Please note the small but important corrections!  I have also included a brightness factor, for easier use.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It's working perfectly. One last question, is there any way where the pictures don't need be the same size, or I just have to crop them?

Comment: Adapting the code to different size images within the Multiply routine would be a lot of work; it would certainly be easier to find a separate solution. Both cropping or placing in the center of a larger bitmap is not really hard to code, provided one knows the dimensions and coordinates..Basically the Graphics.DrawImage method can do that all in one of its many formats.

Comment: I will try to work on some programattical cropping. Again, thanks for your time, you really helped me. :)

Comment: Sure. If you run into trouble ask a new question ;-)